# Do babies have a fight or flight response?

Tags: development, growth, central-nervous-system

Do babies react in the same way as young children and adults in regards to the fight or flight response? If they do not respond in a similar way or don't have a fight or flight response at all then at what age is this developed. My teacher said that babies don't have a fight or flight response and we are unsure of when this develops but I'd like more information if there is any.

Thank you!!

Comment: I think it is 6 months of age, however I found minimal supporting information.